# Can I use Sqlite in a ASP.NET login application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

In a simple page, that requires a user/password to get all access, can I store such a login data in a sqlite database? is this safe? I'm asking because I don't know much about sqlite in background. What I know is that it's just a simple file, that I should think it as "if using fopen()".

Comment: What is safer is avoiding writing your own security libraries, if you use the ASP.NET forms auth and membership providers, you get a lot of security features that have been field tested, here is the sqlite version: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29199/SQLite-Membership-Role-and-Profile-Providers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to believe it wouldn't be secure as long as you configure IIS to **block** serving the file.

Comment: Which can be done by putting it in the App_Data folder, which by default, ASP.NET will not server any file from that folder (but it is accessible to code via the file system)